# PHP is not working on local Apache Webserver

Tags: apache2, php, lamp

I am trying to setup a local wordpress installation and followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-18-04#step-3-%E2%80%94-installing-php) tutorial to setup LAMP.
Unfortunately my Server does not seem to process PHP but I can't find the issue. If I create a file info.php, as described in the tutorial and try to display it in the browser it just shows a blank page.

How can I enable php on the server?